# Getting WampServer to run PHP4 (on Windows 7)

Tags: apache2, wamp, wampserver, php4

I tried to get PHP4 working on WampServer, but whenever I started WampServer, the icon would go to orange but not all the way to green, because Apache wasn't starting.

I've explained how I got it working below. Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Here's how I got it working:

1. Install PHP 4.4.9 from http://www.wampserver.com/en/#addons-php
2. Install Apache 2.0.63 from http://www.wampserver.com/en/#addons-apache
3. Left click the WampServer tray icon, then Apache→Version→2.0.63, wait a minute, then PHP→Version→4.4.9
4. Test Apache by opening the command line and running `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.0.63\bin\apache.exe`. Fix any error reported, and repeat until you don't get any errors.
5. Icon→Apache→Service→Install Service
6. Icon→Restart All Services

---

#### In my case, the Apache errors were:

```
Syntax error on line 22 of C:/wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf: The specified IP address is invalid.
Syntax error on line 22 of C:/wamp/alias/sqlbuddy.conf: The specified IP address is invalid.
Syntax error on line 22 of C:/wamp/alias/webgrind.conf: The specified IP address is invalid.
```

The lines with errors were all the same: `Allow from ::1`. I commented them out to `#Allow from ::1`, which seemed to fix the error.

---

#### If you have trouble switching back to php5:

1. Open `C:\Wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\wampserver.conf`.
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   $phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleName'] = 'php5_module';
   $phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleFile'] = 'php5apache2_4.dll';
   $phpConf['apache']['2.4']['AddModule'] =  '';
   ```
3. Exit WampServer then start it again.

Comment: The reason for the error using `::1` is that `::1` is an IPV6 address, and apache 2.0.63 was not IPV6 aware.